# How to make a multi-lingual keyboard in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, plugins, keyboard

I am searching for a multi-lingual keyboard api or plugin which I can embed in my web app. If the plugin in jquery then its better, caz I am already using jQuery library.

I want keyboard like (or better) than the keyboard that www.shabdkosh.com has. On shabdkosh.com home page, there is a link "key" with the search button, click on the link and then select "Romanized Hindi" from the combobox given next to the "Key" link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and I asked my old friend Google. After a lot of adventure, I conclude the result as follows:
http://debugger.ru/demo/projects/virtualkeyboard/ [IT IS READY]
http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/ [IT NEEDS SMALL MODIFICATIONS]

Answer (score 1):

Google has a [virtual keyboard](http://www.google.com/webelements/#show-virtualkeyboard) widget.

edit: Looks like this is discontinued.